# Optimize code in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
def self.by_vibe(vibe_id)
  self.joins(:vibes).where(vibes: {id: vibe_id})
end
```

This code repeats (with some differences) all over my model, for example:

```
def self.by_music(music_id)
  self.joins(:musics).where(musics: {id: music_id})
end
```

I have four or five of these, and thought of making just one and came out with something like this (for reference, `hash` contains `{:vibes=>2}`):

```
def self.by(hash)
  self.joins(hash.keys.first).where(hash.keys.first.to_s => id = hash.values.first)
end
```

My `self.by_vibe` makes this query:

```
 SELECT "bcls".* FROM "bcls" INNER JOIN "bcls_vibes" ON "bcls_vibes"."bcl_id" = "bcls"."id" INNER JOIN "vibes" ON "vibes"."id" = "bcls_vibes"."vibe_id" WHERE "vibes"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]
```

And my second approach makes this:

```
 SELECT "bcls".* FROM "bcls" INNER JOIN "bcls_vibes" ON "bcls_vibes"."bcl_id" = "bcls"."id" INNER JOIN "vibes" ON "vibes"."id" = "bcls_vibes"."vibe_id" WHERE "bcls"."vibe_id" = 2
```

How can I fix that `where` clause? Notice that the first one (the correct one is  `WHERE "vibes"."id" = $1  [["id", 2]]` and the wrong one is `WHERE "bcls"."vibe_id" = 2`. It's asking for a different table.

Comment: In the `self.by` method you're not using the values of the `hash`. You're just passing `id = 2` to the value of the `where` clause.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that, it was a code I was testing. I'll edit that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the proper way of doing what I was trying to do.

```
def self.by(hash)
  self.joins(hash.keys.first).where(hash.keys.first.to_s => {id: hash.values.first})
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the first value as well as the first key:

```
def self.by(hash)
   self.joins(hash.keys.first).where(
     { hash.keys.first.to_s => { id: hash.values.first } }
   )
end
```

If you're only accepting one key value pair in your hash though it might be better to have two arguments to `by`:

```
def self.by(assoc, obj_id)
  self.joins(assoc).where(assoc => { id: obj_id })
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry about my typo. That id => 2 wasn't part of the original code. I just used 2 so I didn't had to type hash.values.first when I was thinking how to fix the code. I edited that now.